# Tailwind Colors missing with Laravel Jetstream

Tags: laravel-jetstream, laravel-9

Laravel 9.0

Jetstream 2.6

A lot of default colors are missing .. for example, the red color there is three only 100, 600, 700, the gray color 300, 400, 600, 900 is missing and so on !!

I tried the solution to this question but it didn't work

[Tailwind Colors not compiling when used with Laravel Jetstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68989587/tailwind-colors-not-compiling-when-used-with-laravel-jetstream)

composer.json

```json
"require": {
        "php": "^8.0",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0.5",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^9.0",
        "laravel/jetstream": "^2.6",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.14",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.7",
        "livewire/livewire": "^2.5"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.6",
        "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.12",
        "beyondcode/laravel-query-detector": "^1.6",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^6.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^1.0"
    },
```

package.json

```json
"devDependencies": {
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.4.0",
        "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.0",
        "alpinejs": "^3.0.6",
        "axios": "^0.25",
        "browser-sync": "^2.27.7",
        "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.3.0",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "postcss-import": "^14.0.1",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.0.22"
    }
```

tailwind.config.js

```js
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme');

module.exports = {
    content: [
        './vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/*.blade.php',
        './vendor/laravel/jetstream/**/*.blade.php',
        './storage/framework/views/*.php',
        './resources/views/**/*.blade.php',
    ],

    theme: {
      extend: {
        fontFamily: {
          sans: ['Nunito', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
        },
      },
    },

    plugins: [require('@tailwindcss/forms')],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

When I downgrade the Tailwind version from 3.0.0 to 2.2.19 .. everything works fine !!