# Some Tailwind css background colors not working on a laravel project

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css, background-color

I'm a brand new user of tailwind css and would like to perform basic changes for one of my  tag.

I would like to change the background color by using the "bg-blue-500" class. But, for some reason, the color won't show up and the  tag keep using the global grey background color of my page?

I have to tell you that I'm working on a Laravel project. The project is brand new and all versions of both laravel and Jetstream are up to date. Tailwind has been required by Jetstream and I did not install it myself (this was intalled as a dependancy of jetstream packages).

What is more suprising is that I noticed that the "bg-red-500" class worked well for a  tag.
I first thought that the problem was only for  tags but I tried to set the "bg-red-500" class on my  tag and that worked well.
On the contrary, setting the "bg-blue-500" class for the button failed and I lost my bakground color on the button.

Here is my package.json :

```
{
    "private": true,
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@alpinejs/focus": "^3.10.5",
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.2",
        "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.0",
        "alpinejs": "^3.0.6",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
        "axios": "^1.1.2",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.7.5",
        "postcss": "^8.4.14",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.1.0",
        "vite": "^4.0.0"
    }
}
```

Here is my tailwind.config.js :

```
import defaultTheme from 'tailwindcss/defaultTheme';
import forms from '@tailwindcss/forms';
import typography from '@tailwindcss/typography';

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
    content: [
        './vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/*.blade.php',
        './vendor/laravel/jetstream/**/*.blade.php',
        './storage/framework/views/*.php',
        './resources/views/**/*.blade.php',
    ],

    theme: {
      colors: {
            transparent: 'transparent',
            current: 'currentColor',
            //amber: colors.amber,
            black: colors.black,
            blue: colors.blue,
            cyan: colors.cyan,
            emerald: colors.emerald,
            fuchsia: colors.fuchsia,
            gray: colors.trueGray,
            blueGray: colors.blueGray,
            coolGray: colors.coolGray,
            //trueGray: colors.trueGray,
            warmGray: colors.warmGray,
            green: colors.green,
            indigo: colors.indigo,
            lime: colors.lime,
            orange: colors.orange,
            pink: colors.pink,
            purple: colors.purple,
            red: colors.red,
            rose: colors.rose,
            sky: colors.sky,
            teal: colors.teal,
            violet: colors.violet,
            yellow: colors.amber,
            white: colors.white,
        },
        extend: {
            fontFamily: {
                sans: ['Figtree', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
            },
        },
    },

    plugins: [forms, typography],
};
```

Here is my code :

```
<x-admin-layout>
    <div class="container mx-auto p-6">
        <h1 class="text-3xl font-semibold mb-6">Supprimer Academie : {{ $academie->libelle }}</h1>
        <p class="mb-6">Êtes-vous sûr de vouloir supprimer cette académie ? Cette action est irréversible.</p>

        <form action="{{ route('academies.destroy', $academie->id) }}" method="POST">
            @csrf
            @method('DELETE')
            <button type="submit" class="bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">
                Supprimer
            </button>
            <a href="{{ route('academies.index') }}" class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">
                Annuler
            </a>
        </form>
    </div>
</x-admin-layout>
```

As I said, switching both classes for the  and  tags gets me to have the same behaviour on both fields. Only the "bg-red-500" class will work and get me a nice red color...

I'm then pretty sure that my css is not overloaded by another one on my page for any of those two fields...

I tried the given solution here but that did no do the job for me. Am I missing something ?
[Problem already solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68989587/tailwind-colors-not-compiling-when-used-with-laravel-jetstream)

Could you please help me ? (Sorry if I miss something really evident or already answered and I could not see -or understand- the answer...)

Comment: every time you change a color in your html tags, do you run `npm run dev`? Or maybe permanently `npm run watch`?